# How to stop tsc from type checking types that are used for dev/tests

Tags: typescript, webpack

My project uses chai,puppeteer,jest and other test frameworks and libs.
Production build for the project is slow, when running tsc with `--extendedDiagnostics --listFiles` this is the output

```
Files:                        779
Lines:                     140847
Nodes:                     563014
Identifiers:               183460
Symbols:                   375293
Types:                     150026
```

However, I can see that more than half of the files checked are files that are not used by the production code.

My question is, is there an option no not include the @types used for tests in the production build?
I don't want to handpick them and place them in the "exclude" section of the .tsconfig tho.

this is my @types section for the devDependancies.

```
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.59",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/expect-puppeteer": "^2.2.4",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.2",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/payment": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^1.11.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.2",
    "@types/react-credit-cards": "^0.7.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.8",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.3.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.2.0",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.2",
    "@types/react-visibility-sensor": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly an answer but if you are looking to improve compilation time `"skipLibCheck": true` is a good option. This will tell TS to not check the definition files themselves but it will still check uses of the libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using that flag :)